# Why is my input mismatched if the Exception text itself says that it should be matched?

Tags: regex, exception, antlr

I'm lexing a text file and I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: mismatched input 'C' expecting {<EOF>, 'V:', '%', ACCIDENTAL, BASENOTE, 'z', '(', '['}
```

With BASENOTE being defined in antlr as

```
BASENOTE : 'C' | 'D' | 'E' | 'F' | 'G' | 'A' | 'B'
        | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f' | 'g' | 'a' | 'b';
```

I don't understand why it thinks that 'C' is wrong given that it clearly is a BASENOTE token. Can someone shine some light on it?

EDIT:
Before the BASENOTE there are:

```
KEYBASENOTE : 'C' | 'D' | 'E' | 'F' | 'G' | 'A' | 'B';
METERSHORT : 'C' | 'C|';
```

I changed the BASENOTE to say:

```
BASENOTE : KEYBASENOTE | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f' | 'g' | 'a' | 'b';
```

But the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

A lexer rule that also matches `C` is located before `BASENOTE` in your grammar. When the input `C` is assigned a token type, that lexer rule takes priority due to its position.

Comment: Before the BASENOTE there are:
KEYBASENOTE : 'C' | 'D' | 'E' | 'F' | 'G' | 'A' | 'B';

METERSHORT : 'C' | 'C|';

I changed the  BASENOTE to say:

BASENOTE : KEYBASENOTE | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f' | 'g' | 'a' | 'b';

But the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've realised that tokens cannot be defined using other tokens. Fixed that - everything works fine.